# Attribute Converter in attr.s-based hydra Structured Configs

Tags: python, python-attrs, fb-hydra

Is it possible to use [converters](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html#converters) in [`attr.s`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.s)-based [hydra](https://hydra.cc/)-*[structured configs](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/structured_config/intro/)*.

I tried it with this minimal example:

```py
import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore
import attr

@attr.s
class Times10Config:
    num: int = attr.ib(default=42, converter=lambda x: x*10)

cs = ConfigStore.instance()
# Registering the Config class with the name 'config'.
cs.store(name="config", node=Times10Config)

@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg: Times10Config) -> None:
    print(cfg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_app()
```

But running

```bash
python -m my_app num=1
```

results in the output:

```
{'num': 1}
```

While directly instantiating a `Times10Config` in a python interpreter does result in the expected behaviour:

```
In [5]: Times10Config(num=1)
Out[5]: Times10Config(num=10)
```

Comment: FTR: this has nothing to do with attrs. The cfg you're receiving in `my_app` is a **dictionary**. I don't know anything about Hydra, so I can't tell you what exactly is going wrong, but I've stepped through the process with pdb and attrs **doesn't** get involved at any point. Something is wrong with how you're wiring up your ConfigStore and hydra.main.

Comment: Thanks for a lot for looking into it @hynek. It is definitely a hydra question and not an attrs question. Should I rather remove the `python` and `python-attrs` tags?
My code is based on [this example](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/blob/f999139c5d2eae9d4b66dce1ed09a6c944971b6b/examples/tutorials/structured_configs/1_minimal/my_app.py), and the [hydra docs](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/terminology/#structured-config) say you can also use `attr.s`. But now I found [this section](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/structured_config/minimal_example/#duck-typing) that confirms...

Comment: ... that the config class does not actually get initiated and is just used to lie to the static type checker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OmegaConf does not instantiate the underlying objects - it's just using them a descriptors for runtime validation purposes. Any logic defined in the dataclass/attr class is not running normally.

You can convert your config structure to native objects using [OmegaConf.to_object()](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#omegaconf-to-object). Be sure to read the docs for [OmegaConf.to_container()](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#omegaconf-to-container) as well.

In the context of an Hydra application, you could convert your config at the beginning of the run:

```py
@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg: Times10Config) -> None:
    cfg = OmegaConf.to_object(cfg)
    print(cfg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically, but you can add this line:

```py
    cfg = Times10Config(**cfg)
```

to instantiate an object of the config class from the object that is passed to the `hydra.main`-decorated function if you want to actually get a config object of your defined class, and have all the normal attrs mechanisms (validators, converters, etc.) to kick in. But the object that is passed by hydra [is actually just a `DictConfig` object](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/structured_config/minimal_example/#duck-typing) and that type annotation is just used to make the static type checker verify the attributes of the config object.